# Geometric Mean Value Property 

Tags: riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Does anyone know where I could find a proof of a variant of a version of the mean-value property for harmonic functions in Riemannian manifolds?  I'm actually more interested in using an elliptic operator applied to a function, u, integrated over geodesic balls, to control the size of u.  Locally is enough; I don't care about issues involving caustics, et cetera.

Comment: What variant do you want? 

Comment: It seems to me that if you google "mean value property harmonic functions riemannian manifold" you get lots of useful references.

Comment: Did you find what you wanted? 

Answer (score 3):

Schoen & Yau, Lectures on Differential Geometry (International Press, 1994), Chapter II, Section 6: Mean value inequality for subharmonic functions. This is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

(1) Grigorʹyan, A. A.
Stochastically complete manifolds and summable harmonic functions. (Russian) Izv. Akad. Nauk SSSR Ser. Mat. 52 (1988), no. 5, 1102--1108, 1120; translation in
Math. USSR-Izv. 33 (1989), no. 2, 425–432

(2) Leon Karp, Subharmonic functions, harmonic mappings and isometric immersions (pp. 133--142); in Seminar on Differential Geometry.
Papers presented at seminars held during the academic year 1979–1980. Edited by Shing Tung Yau. Annals of Mathematics Studies, 102. Princeton University Press, Princeton, N.J.; University of Tokyo Press, Tokyo, 1982.